# Can Convolutional layers be used as classification/output layer instead of dense layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I want to use convolutional layers as my output/prediction layer instead of dense layer. Is this feasible? if yes, please suggest how?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated, here is how you can help the people here answer your question. First, please explain what kind of use-cases will your model will be? Second, please explain why you would want to use convolution as final prediction layer. I am not saying the practice is impossible in fact it is very possible but answering only yes for this will not be a satisfying either for you right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes. If you use a filter with size equal to the input size, it'll produce a 1x1 image (considering 2D case for the sake of simplicity) because it won't slide anywhere. This 1x1 image contains a real number as if the entire image goes into a neuron in a dense layer. So, if you use $N$ filters, you'll have $N$ outputs as if you have $N$ neurons in the dense layer ahead. Note that this makes no difference whatsoever compared to using a dense layer so I think there is no point doing this. You may also need to add a softmax layer if your problem has more than two classes, or implement a choice strategy (e.g. choose the class with max output) among different outputs if you code the network yourself.